# Are all new datomic ids greater than previous ones?

Tags: datomic

I am writing an application that syncs data between a client and server, and so I frequently need to check whether an entity on the server is newer than any entity on the client.

Does Datomic guarantee that all new entities will have ids greater than previously existing entities? Just need to know before I make that a big part of my program logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity ids are composed *at least* of both the partition in which entities are created and a monotonically increasing number. If you look at entity ids as numeric values then they won't have sequential ids.

Instead you should look at their [transaction](http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html) and compare their `:db/txInstant` attribute value, which is created by default and attached to all transactions on the systems. `:db/txInstant`'s value is a timestamp that captures the instant in time when the transaction took place.

Also, take a look at [`(tx-report-queue)`](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/tx-report-queue), which is used to monitor or synchronize data with external systems. It gives you access to the Datomic push-based model of novelty broadcasted by the transactor.